View not updating when relationship array changes
I'm working on a SwiftUI app using SwiftData for persistence. I have a TaskModel class with a relationship to DailyProgress objects. When I update the progress, the view doesn't reflect the changes. Here's an example to demonstrate: (You can just copy everything)
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct SO_model_testApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            TaskModel.self,
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    }
}


@Model
class DailyProgress: Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
    var id = UUID()
    var date: Date
    var goal: Int
    var task: TaskModel?
    
    init(date: Date, goal: Int) {
        self.date = date
        self.goal = goal
    }
    
    var description: String {
        "\(date) - \(goal)"
    }
    
    var weekOfYear: Int {
        let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
        return calendar.component(.weekOfYear, from: date)
    }
    
    var yearForWeekOfYear: Int {
        let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
        return calendar.component(.yearForWeekOfYear, from: date)
    }
}

@Model
class TaskModel: Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var goal: Int
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
    var progress: [DailyProgress] = []
        
    init(name: String, goal: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.goal = goal
    }
    
    func goalForDate(_ date: Date) -> Int {
        let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
        for dailyProgress in progress {
            if calendar.isDate(dailyProgress.date, inSameDayAs: date) {
                return dailyProgress.goal
            }
        }
        return 0
    }
    
    @MainActor
    func updateGoal(date: Date, value: Int) {
        let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
        let dateIndex = progress.firstIndex(where: { calendar.isDate($0.date, inSameDayAs: date) })
        
        if let index = dateIndex {
            progress[index].goal += value
            if progress[index].goal <= 0 {
                progress.remove(at: index)
            }
        } else if value > 0 {
            let newProgress = DailyProgress(date: date, goal: value)
            progress.append(newProgress)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Query private var tasks: [TaskModel]
    @State private var selectedTask: TaskModel?
    @State private var showingNewTaskSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(tasks) { task in
                TaskRow(task: task)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedTask = task
                    }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Tasks")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {
                        showingNewTaskSheet = true
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(item: $selectedTask) {
                TaskDetailView(task: $0)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingNewTaskSheet) {
                NewTaskView(isPresented: $showingNewTaskSheet)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TaskRow: View {
    let task: TaskModel
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(task.name)
            Spacer()
            Text("Goal: \(task.goal)")
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        }
    }
}

struct TaskDetailView: View {
    @Bindable var task: TaskModel
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @State private var today = Date()
    
    var todayTotal: Int {
        task.goalForDate(Date())
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Task Details")) {
                TextField("Task Name", text: $task.name)
                Stepper("Daily Goal: \(task.goal)", value: $task.goal, in: 1...100)
            }
            
            Section(header:                 Text("Total: \(todayTotal)")) {
                Text("Total: \(task.goalForDate(today))")
                Button(action: {
                    task.updateGoal(date: today, value: 1)
                }) {
                    Label("Log Progress", systemImage: "plus.circle")
                }
            }
            
//            Section(header: Text("All Progresses")) {
//                if task.progress.isEmpty {
//                    Text("No progress logged yet")
//                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
//                } else {
//                    ForEach(task.progress.sorted(by: { $0.date > $1.date })) { progress in
//                        HStack {
//                            Text(progress.date, style: .date)
//                            Spacer()
//                            Text("Goal: \(progress.goal)")
//                        }
//                    }
//                }
//            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Task Details")
    }
}

struct NewTaskView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext

    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    
    @State private var taskName = ""
    @State private var goal = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                TextField("Task Name", text: $taskName)
                Stepper("Daily Goal: \(goal)", value: $goal, in: 1...100)
            }
            .navigationTitle("New Task")
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading: Button("Cancel") {
                    isPresented = false
                },
                trailing: Button("Save") {
                    modelContext.insert(TaskModel(name: taskName, goal: goal))
                    isPresented = false
                }
                .disabled(taskName.isEmpty)
            )
        }
    }
}

When I tap the "Log Progress" button, updateGoal is called, but the "Total" text doesn't update to reflect the new value.
If you uncomment commented code, then it works fine, because I think the section needs this progress data to show. But why doesn't it get updated when commented out? I still use daily progress implicitly in task.goalForDate(), so I expect it to be updated as well.

Note, there is no need for Identifiable in your model classes, @Model already conforms to that.
Also, NavigationView is deprecated use NavigationStack instead.

If you are using SwiftData there is zero reason for NavigationView and navigationBarItems

@workingdogsupportUkraine
I know, yes. This is not what I use in the real app. This is just a quick example, it should not matter in this case

Not very helpful but this works fine as is on macOS with the latest Xcode 16 beta.

I have now tested for iOS as well and while I can reproduce for 17.5 it works fine for iOS 18 beta

The problem is that when you update a related object in your function this will not trigger an update in SwiftUI since the view engine doesn't get notified about the update.
This seems to be a bug that has been fixed in iOS 18, macOS 15 but as a workaround for older versions one way is to use a property wrapper like @State to get updates for the related object as well.
So first we change the function in the model to return the found object instead
func goalForDate(_ date: Date) -> DailyProgress? {
    let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
    return progress.first(where: { calendar.isDate($0.date, inSameDayAs: date) })
}

Then we add the property
@State private var currentProgress: DailyProgress?

and set it in onAppear
.onAppear {
    currentProgress = task.goalForDate(Date())
}

and of course read the property where needed
var todayTotal: Int {
    currentProgress?.goal ?? 0
}

//...

Text("Total: \(currentProgress?.goal ?? 0)")

Now the view will update whenever the object held by currentProgress is updated by the updateGoal function.

This is a bit simplified since for instance there is a today Date property and if that can change you need to use onChange as well.

You're missing a @Query for the DailyProgress which match the required task. You can use a predicate for that, e.g. something like:
 @Query var progresses: [DailyProgress]

 init(task: TaskModel) {      
    let predicate = #Predicate<DailyProgress> {
$0.task == task
    }
    _progresses = Query(filter: predicate, sort: \ DailyProgress.date)
}

You can see this pattern in TripListItem.swift in Adopting SwiftData for a Core Data app.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. And I don't need progresses implicitly, so to speak. I still want all of my logic to be inside TaskModel, and that should operate with DailyProgress. It updates the database just fine. It's just that the UI doesn't get updated automatically for some reason :(

@Query definitely works to update the UI could you explain more what isn't working
